# iOS initializing a static object's member fails

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5

I have the following code that fails when i run it. my .h file:

```
 @interface OutlineManager : NSObject
    {
            NSMutableArray* mOutlines;
    }

    @property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray* Outlines;


    +(void)initialize;

    @end

    static OutlineManager* outlnManager;
```

in the .m file:

```
#import "OutlineManager.h"

@implementation OutlineManager

@synthesize Outlines = mOutlines;

+(void)initialize
{
    outlnManager = [[[OutlineManager superclass]alloc]init];
    if(outlnManager)
    {
        outlnManager.Outlines = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init]; //it crashes here
    }
    NSLog(@"OUTLINEMANAGER INITIALIZED");
}

@end
```

when i run (void)initialize the application crashes in the if section where i put the comment, but i don"t know why. Can't I init an array of a static object like this?

I guess it's something very basic, but i'm pretty new at Obj C /iOS , so please don't hold this against me.

Thank you very much for your help!

Sincerely, Zoli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

```
outlnManager = [[[OutlineManager superclass]alloc]init];
```

That superclass means you calling alloc on NSObject and not on OutlineManager.
Just replace this line with this:

```
outlnManager = [[OutlineManager alloc]init];
```

Oh and you should declare your static variables in the .m file.

Comment: that works! However when i cant to add an object to outlnManager.Outlines in an other .m file because it's null there. When does it become null. Does ARC free it?

Answer (score 0):

OutlineManager.h:

replace

```
static OutlineManager* outlnManager;
```

with:

```
OBJC_EXPORT OutlineManager* outlnManager;
```

and add in OutlineManager.m:

```
OutlineManager* outlnManager = nil;
+(void)initialize { // you should rename it to an other name.. initialize will be called twice
    outlnManager = [[OutlineManager alloc]init];
    if(outlnManager) {
        outlnManager.Outlines = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    NSLog(@"OUTLINEMANAGER INITIALIZED");
}
```